# =VLOOKUP() function performed on dollar value displays value without "$"

Tags: microsoft-excel, vlookup, worksheet-function

I'm not entirely sure how to present pleasant-looking spreadsheet representations on SE, so I would appreciate any advice on that issue given on the side.

I want the B2 cell to display the salary associated with the name selected from the drop-down menu in A2. This works, but the values that get displayed in B2 are missing the dollar signs and commas found in B5:B7. What can I do to force the formula to return my values without changing my formatting?

LEGEND:

|LIST| represents a drop-down list created using the Data Validation window. The source for the list is A5:A7.

|FUNC| is the function =VLOOKUP(A2, A5:B7, 2, 0)

```
÷      A          B
1    Person     Salary
2    |LIST|     |FUNC|
3
4    Worker     Salary
5    Bob        $23,000
6    Rob        $21,000
7    Cobb       $150,000
```

Thanks you!

Comment: The dollar signs and commas are part of the format, a property of the cell, they are not part of the values stored in the cell. Simply apply the same format to `B2`.

Comment: Well, there you go! That was easy. Thank you very much! Although the solution was simple, the headache locating a solution on google or SE was giving me was enormous.

Answer (score 1):

If it's purely for aesthetics, you could simply concatenate text onto the salary.

Eg, Set B2:

```
="$"&VLOOKUP(A2, A5:B7, 2, 0)
```